# QApplication::desktop returns null

Tags: c++, qt, screenshot

I want to make a screenshot of an entire workspace (we have multiple monitors here). Currently I have working version for GDI, but now i'm stuck with porting my software to Linux.

```
QDesktopWidget* win = qApp->desktop();
auto id = win->winId(); // CRASH HAPPENS HERE, win == nullptr
QImage pixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow(id).toImage(); //won't come here ever.
```

Dunno, if it will help to understand the problem, but this is what i'm working with:

- VirtualBox VM with 2 monitors 1920x1080
- Debian 4.17.8-1 (2018-07-20)
- x86_64 GNU/Linux
- LightDM + XFCE4.
- xserver-xorg version (according to dpkg -s): 1:7.7+19

Yeah, I know, the topic of taking a screenshot under Linux appears here from time to time (Xlib and stuff), but this question is strictly about Qt's way of doing it, and why it works on Windows (slow, though), but not on Linux as well.

Comment: The QDesktopWidget class is obsolete in newer version of Qt. Can you tell specify the Qt version you are using?

Comment: @NishantSingh It is 5.11.1.

Comment: Try using the new API QScreen::grabWindow(id)

Comment: Try to add `if (win) {` before `auto id = win->winId();`.

Comment: Take a peek [at this repository](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/tooling) and see if the screenshot code there will work. It works at least for OS X and Windows, and is used to take automagic screenshots of example code I post here :) It is targeted for screenshots of the window only, not the entire desktop, but it's a simple change to modify that.

Comment: @scopchanov, I already noted that it is nullptr. No need to double-check it. I want to know why it is nullptr.

Comment: @KubaOber, I'll check it out, thanks!